# c variable value for parent and child process

Tags: c++, c, parent-child

I am writing a c code for making parent and child process

```
int main
{
    pid_t =pid;
    pid=fork();
    int a=21;
    if(pid==0)
    {
        a=25;
        printf("%d child \n",&a);
        printf("%d child \n",a);
    }
    if(pid!=0)
    {

        printf("%d parent \n",&a);
        printf("%d parent \n",a);
    }
}
```

in my output address of variable a printed by both parent and child process are same.
I have studied that when we fork a process each child process creates a copy of variables.
if this is true then address must be different.

if this is false then when child process executes first then it will change the value at the location where a is stored.
but my parent process is printing the value as 21 (according to its copy..)

Comment: C++ and C are different languages. Please choose one in the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fork` causes the *entire address space* to be copied. That means variables will have the same addresses in the parent and child processes.

Moreover, the copied address space is independent. If the child changes a value at a particular address, the parent will not see it. It does not matter who executes first, the parent will always print `21` in this case.

You might be thinking of **threading**, where the address space is shared between multiple threads.

Comment: then this means that the address we see is the logical address not physical

Comment: @shivgarg, in any ordinary c program when you print out an address it is a virtual address